# Hanging Internet Wire Clip From one House to another

Tags: networking, wired-networking

I am trying to find out a way to hang a Cat6 Outdoor Wire from one House to another without fear that it will stretch and cut at one end after some time. My ISP uses a somewhat clip to hold the hanging wire but I can't find out how it's called. Could anyone kindly give me some ideas?

Comment: The typical means of running such a wire would be lashing it to a suspension strand or using a self-supporting cable with a messenger wire like this: https://www.amazon.com/CERTICABLE-SHIELDED-SUPPORTING-MESSENGER-CONNECTORS/dp/B00FM49ZPA

Comment: I would strongly suggest using a wireless link instead. High-speed, short range, professional grade wireless links are available for less than $100 per end. (I'm personally a fan of Ubiquiti AirMax, but there are lots of other brands too.)

Comment: Be sure to add lightning protection at *both* ends, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Ethernet-Surge-Protector-Gigabit-1000Mbs/dp/B00805VUD8 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I'm going to suggest that Cat 6 (or 5, or copper/metal data cable of any sort) is a BAD idea between buildings. Or at least one you should only attempt with some SERIOUS lightning protect at each end, but, having seen enough fried lightning protection, still a bad idea.

[image: Drop wire clamp]

This is a telephone drop wire clamp. "Wedge clamp" is more generic but may find you huge ones intended for electrical service wires, not data. I would only suggest using it with an all-dielectric drop fiber, which is a *specially designed to be as much like a telephone drop cable as possible* fiber cable, and much less subject to problems from lightning. It's also easier for most people to handle than "normal" fiber cable as it has sturdy reinforcing rods that help to limit bend radius.

In practice for most people, I agree with the comment from David Schwartz - a wireless point-to-point link is less money and far less subject to getting fried than copper, and far easier for anyone not in possession of a fiber termination kit (and the skills to use it) to set up.

Comment: Yea there's a huge disadvantage for the Copper Wire but that's the easiest root I've found, the wire cost less than the Wireless Access Point. There's Lighting protect for Cat6/5 Cable? Could you link me to some "Wedge Clamp"? Can't find it out on stores.

Comment: You won't find them at most consumer oriented stores, you need a very well-stocked electrical specialist with a data bent. But you can't have looked very hard, google finds plenty. http://www.linemen-tools.com/category_s/584.htm http://www.newtechindustries.com/drop-wire-clamp-6-pair-stainless-steel-dimpled-shim/  http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-PAIR-Allied-Bolt-903-Stainless-Steel-Drop-Wire-Clamps-/331634350003?hash=item4d36f297b3:g:7FMAAOSw9N1V11ur Ethernet Surge Protector: http://www.balticnetworks.com/ubiquiti-ethernet-surge-protector.html

Comment: That Ubiquiti protector does not even claim to protect from potentially destructive surges.  Ethernet protectors that do always - as in always - have a dedicated and low impedance wire to earth ground.  That is why all incoming wires (telephone, cable, satellite dish, etc) are required to enter at the service entrance.  Otherwise that low impedance connection cannot exist.  Other protectors that actually claim to do protection always have a short connection to earth ground.  Always.

Answer (score -1):

I know that sounds nasty,  but you can try to put it underground, at fixed positions,  this way you will prevent it to stretch or something.

Or you can go with a wire rope and some zip ties.. If you want something clean and easy go with previous recommendation.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: That's ain't my question. Sorry!

Comment: Actually he did since the cable must be a specific type capable of supporting its own weight, in wind, and with snow.  That wire rope or messenger wire is another option necessary to make possible what you are asking.  Lightning means the cable must enter at each buildings service entrance.  Otherwise an incoming lightning strike to one building is a direct strike to all electronics inside the other.  Another concern (not fully explained) addressed by another poster.